# Dumping data from MySql to MongoDB

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

There is a table event_logs There are about 16 million entries in the table. Database is MySQL. The database is stored in Google Cloud.

My task is dump this data into MongoDB. Before dumping data I need to convert each row into JSON document.

### Table schema issues

1.There is no `auto_increment_id` and no primary keys in the table

### Tried in following ways

1.In Java using JDBC driver streamed results in ResultSet, but the problem is for first 300k results it took less time , after that it's taking long time to getting results from database server why ??

2.Splitted queries into multiple queries and used limit (like limit 1000000,100000) , but the problem is if row number starts from large number like 1000000 it's taking long time to get results. Looks like MySql is still starting from beginning even if I put row number like 1000000 and throwing results up to this number.

Please suggest solutions to efficient way to copy from MySql to MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

at first you can try to set ResultSet fetch size that way:

```
...
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.setFetchSize(2000); // perhaps more...
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("YOUR QUERY");
...
```

or you could just export your MYSQL data (CSV/XML) and then import they using this [import-export-tool](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/) 
converting each row into JSON document could be done after that, by parsing CSV file

also you can try to create a Statement using this parameters:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
               ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
               ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: I tried in that way statement.setFetchSize(2000); but still Im getting very slow results.

Comment: try to set 10000 or more. How do you iterate over the resultset?

Comment: Im just iterating in while loop while(resultSet.next()){}

Comment: statement = connection.createStatement(
     java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
     java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

Comment: Im using the above one instead SCROLL_INSENSITIVE Im using java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mongify` a `Ruby` based application for super simple conversion from `MySQL` to `MongoDB`